# Multi-page form using TFmail script

Tags: html, forms, http-post

I have set up a TFmail script and got it working properly using a single page form.

Now, I think of making a form that spans over 2 HTML pages, but I'm not sure how to set up the submit button to submit and link to a different site at the same time. Is it possible to do this?